# Inverse Fourier transform of $\exp(A \operatorname{sinc} (B t) )$

Tags: integration, special-functions, fourier-transform

I need to evaluate the integral
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\Big({-i x t} + A \operatorname{sinc}(Bt)\Big)dt $$
either exactly or for any level of approximation beyond first order for $B\rightarrow 0$. Expanding the $\operatorname{sinc}$ function, the first order approximation is
$$ I =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\Big({-i x t} + A \Big[1-\frac{(Bt)^2}{3!}+ \cdots \Big]\Big)\,dt \approx e^A \sqrt{\frac{3! \pi}{A B^2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{3! x^2}{4 A B^2}\Big) . $$
The next order approximation would involve a convolution between this Gaussian solution and the inverse transform of a function like $e^{kt^4}$. I think this diverges.

Therefore I'm asking for advice: is there a closed form for the initial integral $I$ in terms of special functions? Or if not, is there a means to evaluate
$$ J = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-itx + k t^4}dt$$
in terms of special functions? Does this integral even converge? Any thoughts are appreciated !

A thought: is this related to a stable distribution? [https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#:~:text=The%20characteristic%20function%20of%20a%20strictly%2Dstable%20distribution%20with%20exponent,only%20be%20a%20Cauchy%20distribution](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#:%7E:text=The%20characteristic%20function%20of%20a%20strictly%2Dstable%20distribution%20with%20exponent,only%20be%20a%20Cauchy%20distribution).

Comment: I changed $A\text{sinc}(Bt)$ to $A\operatorname{sinc}(Bt)$ and you see the difference in visual appearance. That the spacing is context-dependent is seen if you consider something like $(C+A)\operatorname{sinc}(Bt),$ where the space to the left of $\operatorname{sinc}$ is smaller than in that earlier expression.

Comment: The integral $I$ diverges. The Fourier transform is
$$\mathcal F[t \mapsto e^{A \operatorname {sinc}(B t)}](x) =
2 \pi \delta(x) +
 \mathcal F[t \mapsto e^{A \operatorname {sinc}(B t)} - 1](x).$$
The Fourier transform on the rhs is an $L^2$ function. Since the distributional limit of $e^{A \operatorname {sinc}(B t)}$ is $e^A$, we have
$$\lim_{B \to 0} \mathcal F[t \mapsto e^{A \operatorname {sinc}(B t)}](x) =
2 \pi e^A \delta(x).$$

Comment: @Maxim I'm not familiar with distributional limits, but now that you raise the point, it makes sense in context that this integral would be a delta function. Can you elaborate on progression from the first equation to the second?

Comment: Actually I misread: This is rather clear from $\lim_{B\rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{-itx + A[1 + O(B)]} = 2\pi e^A \delta(x)$, but this isn't enough as it's only to zeroth order in $B$. I expect also some terms contributing near $|x| < 1/A$. I'm reminded of the Fourier transform of the modified Bessel function, which is a delta function plus a rational function.

Comment: Let $f(t) = e^{A \operatorname {sinc}(B t)}$. The FT of distributions is continuous, we can interchange the FT and the limit. For the next term, since $d^4(e^{A \operatorname {sinc}(t)})/dt^4$ is bounded, we have
$$\left| f(t) - e^A  + \frac {A e^A (B t)^2} 6 \right| \leq M (B t)^4, \\
(\mathcal F[f], \phi) =
(f, \mathcal F[\phi]) =
e^A \int_{\mathbb R} \mathcal F[\phi](x) dx -
 \frac {A e^A B^2} 6 \int_{\mathbb R} x^2\mathcal F[\phi](x) dx +
O(B^4), \\
\mathcal F[f](x) =
2 \pi e^A \delta(x) +
 \frac {\pi A e^A} 3 \delta''(x) B^2 +
O(B^4).$$

Answer (score 1):

For $$J = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-itx + k t^4}\,dt$$ provided that $k<0$,a CAS gives in terms of a generalized hypergeometric function
$$J=\frac{2\, \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) }{(-k)^{1/4}}\,\,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};-\frac{x^4}{4^4 k}\right)+\frac{ \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{16 (-k)^{3/4}}x^2\,\, _0F_2\left(;\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^4}{4^4 k}\right)$$